# Perform analysis on last three values of a FileMaker dataset

Tags: filemaker

My end goal is to have a box change color when the last 3 records input into a field (based on the time of input) in FileMaker achieve a certain criteria (ex. variance < 2). I would like to know how to make this happen, or how a calculation/script can be written to only look at the last 3 records.

Comment: The "last 3 records" is an ill-defined term.Records can be found and/or sorted at will.

Comment: You are correct. I meant to say, the last 3 records input to the system, based on time.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could approach this. A simple one would be to use a script to:

1. Show all records in the given table;
2. Unsort them (assuming they were entered in chronological order; otherwise sort them by creation timestamp);
3. Omit all records except the last three;
4. Get the value of a summary field defined as Standard Deviation of your value field;
5. Set a global variable/field to the square of the returned value.

Then use the global variable/field to conditionally format your "box".

---

If you don't want to use a script, you will have to define a relationship in order to get the last three values in the table, regardless of the current found set and/or sort order. Or you may use the `ExecuteSQL()` function for this.