# Multiple AND statements in a FileMaker calculation

Tags: filemaker

I want to calculate if a value falls outside of 10% of the last two values added to a database. This calculation is not giving me correct feedback when I have 'Weight" values close to 10, or from 100-110. Otherwise it works fine.

```
Case (
Get(RecordNumber) ≤ 2 ; "Continue Collecting Data" ;


(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; Get(RecordNumber)-2))*.9) ≤ Weight) and
(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; Get(RecordNumber)-2))*1.1) ≥ Weight) and

(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; Get(RecordNumber)-1))*.9) ≤ Weight) and
(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; Get(RecordNumber)-1))*1.1) ≥ Weight);

"Stable";

"Unstable")
```

Comment: `Get(RecordNumber)` gets the position of the current record in the current found set, under the current sort order. You cannot use it to get "the last two values added to a database" - as you were already  told in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793152/perform-analysis-on-last-three-values-of-a-filemaker-dataset).

Comment: Okay, assuming my current sort order is how I want it, and I want to use the information from the previous two rows in the current sort order, why is the above code not functioning when values of 10 or 100-110 are input.

Comment: Please post an exact and reproducible examples of 3 consecutive values that do not produce the expected result. Also make sure that the Weight field's type is Number, and that the calculation is unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to start with the assumption that your table includes fields for both the primary key and the creation timestamp. If not, I would highly recommend adding both to this table and every other table you create.

Assuming these fields are in place, you need to create another occurrence of the table on which this layout is based, then relate the primary key to itself via a Cartesian (×) join. Sort the relationship by creation timestamp descending. Your calculation is then:

```
Case (

(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; 1 ) *.9 ) ≤ Weight) and
(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; 1 ) *1.1 ) ≥ Weight) and

(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; 2 ) *.9 ) ≤ Weight) and
(((GetNthRecord ( Weight ; 2 ) *1.1 ) ≥ Weight);

"Stable";

"Unstable")
```

Another thing I noticed is that your code is kind of complex. The Let function can make things easier to read, and your four criteria can be cut down to whether either difference is out of range. So, a simpler version becomes:

```
Let ( [
         #weight1 = GetNthRecord ( all::weight ; 1 ) ;
         #weight2 = GetNthRecord ( all::weight ; 2 )

] ; //end define Let

   Case (

      Abs ( #weight1 - weight ) > .1 ; "Unstable" ;

      Abs ( #weight2 - weight ) > .1 ; "Unstable" ;

         "Stable"

   ) //end Case

) //end Let
```

Does that help?

Comment: I am afraid your answer makes no sense. Your calculation is getting its values from the found set in the same table occurrence where it is defined; your added self-join relationship plays no part in it. And your "simplification" will produce radically different results from those returned by the original formula.

Comment: Dang… thanks, Michael. I was obviously in a rush. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using FileMaker v12 or later, this looks like a good place to use the ExecuteSQL function (not the script step) to retrieve the last two values. You could do something like this:

```
Let (

sqlQuery = "
     SELECT t.weight
     FROM MyTable t
     WHERE t.id <> ?
     ORDER BY t.id DESC
     FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
" ;

ExecuteSQL ( sqlQuery ; "" ; "" ; MyTable::id )

)
```

This query assumes you have a unique 'id' field (i.e. a primary key) that's defined as an 'auto-enter serial' value. The WHERE clause makes sure that the current record (presumably the one the user is entering) is not included in the query. The ORDER BY DESC clause forces the last two records to the top where we can fetch the 'weight' values easily into a value list.

Assuming you use a 'Set Variable' script step to put the query results into $lastValues, you can then test for whether they are in range like so:

```
Let ( [

lastValue1 = GetValue ( $lastValues ; 1 ) ;
lastValue2 = GetValue ( $lastValues ; 2 ) ;

Value1_InRange = lastValue1 - Abs ( lastValue1 - weight ) >= ( 0.9 * lastValue1 ) ;
Value2_InRange = lastValue2 - Abs ( lastValue2 - weight ) >= ( 0.9 * lastValue2 ) 

] ;

Value1_InRange and Value2_InRange // returns 1 if both values within range, 0 if not

)
```

If I were doing this, I would put the above range-checking code into a custom function so it's generic and can be easily reused:

```
IsWithinRange ( valueToTest ; lastValue ; range ) = 
lastValue - Abs ( lastValue - valueToTest ) >= ( ( 1 - range ) * lastValue )
```

Then the above range-checking code can be reduced to:

```
IsWithinRange ( MyTable::weight ; GetValue ( $lastValues ; 1 ) ; 0.1 ) & 
IsWithinRange ( MyTable::weight ; GetValue ( $lastValues ; 2 ) ; 0.1 )
```

And one last note.. if you use the ExecuteSQL function in a calculated field, be sure to make it 'unstored' so that it only executes when needed. However, I would recommend you avoid that altogether and simply call it from a script step like 'Set Variable'. That way you can control exactly when it executes.

Hope that helps!